# How do I make a regex that allow all languages but not special characters?

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm really not getting this. I'm quite new to regex.

I try to validate a form with names in it with jQuery Validate together with a regex rule. I have managed to write the function but need the right regex.

The fields should allow all languages' names, but not allowing the special characters like "$∞§€" and all those characters that do not belong in names.

Any suggestions on how to do this

Comment: What characters don't belong in names, exactly? http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make your regex to work with Unicode, as shown [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), you would need to do something like so: `\p{L} or \p{Letter}: any kind of letter from any language`

Comment: Great! That explains a lot. Any ideas how to make that work in javascript?

Comment: @user1788243: You could simply build the regex you need and follow any tutorial on regular expressions with javascript.